# Relationship between prediction model accuracy and measurement rate

Tags: predictive-models, signal-processing

I have a 2D signal that I can measure, with a Nyquist frequency of $f_{s}$ Hz. I also have a prediction model that tries to predict a few seconds ahead what the signal value will be. I have a choice of several sensors that I can use to measure my signal, with various tradeoffs. What I want to understand, is what the relationship will be between prediction quality and the measurement rate of my sensor. Assuming that the accuracy of all sensors is the same, it seems to me that I would be able to produce better predictions if my sensor was operating at a high frequency, but this is only an intuition. What theoretical frameworks (if any) can I read up on to make a more informed decision?

Comment: What is your argument that a higher frequency should lead to better predictions?

Comment: Well, if I'm operating above the Nyquist frequency for the signal, I should get a better reconstruction. It seems intuitive to me that a better reconstruction would make it easier to make predictions. But I'm not sure about this.